# How to calculate this integral $I=lim f^n d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let X be such that $\mu (X)=1$, and $f$ be a measurable function such that $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty[$

Calculate $I=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X f^n d\mu$ and  $I=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X atan(f^n) d\mu$.

I don't really know where to start and what to do, I'm a beginner in measure theory.
Thank you.

The exercise tells to use the sets where $f$ is less than $1$ and when it isn't.

Comment: Can you see that $f^n \to 0$ on the set $\{x : f(x) < 1\}$?

Comment: Does $f^n$ mean the $n$-th power, as in $x\mapsto(f(x)^n)$, or the $n$-fold composition of $f$, as in $f(f(f(\cdots f(x)\cdots)))$?  Or maybe something else?

Comment: It means the n-th power I deduce from the indication of the exercise.

@GEdgar, I could see that, but couldn't think anything else for the other case.

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $f$? As it stands, there is no reason to believe that $f^n$ is integrable.

Comment: $f^n$ is measurable and nonnegative.  So $\int f^n$ exists in $[0,+\infty]$.